# iOS and Android mapping image resolution

Tags: android, ios

So currently I have app on both iOS and Android, while Android is a new app.

If I have 1x 2x and 3x images for iOS app. Which one comes near to Android ldpi/mdpi/hdpi?

Does 1x most likely match to ldpi resolution?

Answer (score 6):

this image can help you to resolve your problem ! :) hope it help

[image]